# How do I compare the relative frequencies in R?

Tags: r, frequency, frequency-analysis

I ran a study asking participants to choose between options A, B, and C based on various parameters.

For example: Which of the following did you find to be most inspirational?

My data looks something like this:

| ID | Inspiration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | C |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | C |
| 7 | B |
| 8 | C |
| 9 | A |
| 10 | B |
| 11 | A |
| 12 | B |

I have calculated the relative frequencies so my data now looks like this:

| ID | Inspiration | Proportion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | .25 |
| 2 | C | .33 |
| 3 | B | .42 |
| 4 | C | .33 |
| 5 | B | .42 |
| 6 | C | .33 |
| 7 | B | .42 |
| 8 | C | .33 |
| 9 | A | .25 |
| 10 | B | .42 |
| 11 | A | .25 |
| 12 | B | .42 |

My question is: how do I test to see if the relative frequency of each choice is significantly different from one another? That is, how do I know if the frequency of which people chose Option A is significantly different from the frequency of which they chose either B or C?

I have tried running t-tests, anovas, chi-squared tests, and two-proportion z-tests, but none of these options seem to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First use `dput()` to provide your data:

```
dta <- structure(list(ID = 1:12, Inspiration = c("A", "C", "B", "C", 
"B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Now construct a table of the relative frequencies:

```
tbl <- table(dta$Inspiration)
tbl 
# A B C 
# 3 5 4
```

Now the null hypothesis that each choice is selected equally (i.e. frequency of A == B == C):

```
chisq.test(tbl)
# 
#   Chi-squared test for given probabilities
# 
# data:  tbl
# X-squared = 0.5, df = 2, p-value = 0.7788
# 
# Warning message:
# In chisq.test(tbl) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

No significant difference between the categories.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! For clarity, why is there only 2 degrees of freedom in the chi-squared test? And what would the interpretation look like if the test had been significant (i.e., how would I know which frequencies were significantly different from one another?)

Comment: The test is that all are the same so you don't get results about individual comparisons. That would involve testing all of the pairs and adjusting the p-values for multiple comparisons. The number of degrees of freedom is one less than the number of categories.